# What does "play in" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

In the book *Designing for Growth: A Design Thinking Toolkit for Managers* ([Google Books Link](https://books.google.com/books?id=sR42AAAAQBAJ)) the following sentence occurs:

> The designers envision several futuristic worlds to prototype for and play in.

What is the meaning of the phrase "play in" in this context?

Comment: We need more information.  For example, do you already know what "play in" means in a sentence like "Let's go play in the park."?  If so, what is it about the given sentence that is giving you trouble?

Comment: I know what "play in" means in your sample sentence, and its meaning doesn't make sense in my sentence. Does it?

Comment: I would guess it means the type of thing that children often do.  Adults do it too, when they're not wasting time on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @cobaltduck -  I read in meta that posting answers in comments would discourage other users to post answers. I find your comment to precisely answer OP's question. I request you to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a paraphrasing of the original that I believe captures the author's intent, but re-orders the words for clarity:

> The designers envision several futuristic worlds; they will prototype for and will play in these worlds.

This use of the phrase "play in" has the same sense as play in a sandbox, play in the park, play in the back yard, and so on- just in a *figurative* sense as opposed to a *literal* one.

Comment: If you think it's "figurative" you don't know developers very well.

Comment: @HotLicks- On the contrary, I *am* one!  But for purposes of this site, and this question, well....